# What version of HTML does Java use for rendering markedup text

Tags: java, html, swing, syntax, version

I was just wondering what version of the HTML syntax does Java 5, 6 and 7 support, I don't seem to find any documentation online regarding this.

EDIT: Sorry, to clarify, I mean in rendering UI stuff through Swing, like JLabel text values etc.

Comment: I believe OP meant the Swing HTML UI rendering

Comment: Ya, sorry, I meant in rendering UI, like JLabel text etc.

Comment: Might want to take a look at JavaFx which has great HTML capabilities. Here is a nice tutorial which shows how to use JavaFx and Swing together to render HTML content: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/swing/swing-fx-interoperability.htm

Comment: @DavidKroukamp: Might a little heavy for a label component, but good to know nonetheless!

Comment: This question is perfectly valid.

Comment: Maybe it was a little vague, I just wanted to know whether I could use HTML 5 syntax or not, and which version of Java supports which version of HTML, thats all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [HTMLEditorKit JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/HTMLEditorKit.html):

> The Swing JEditorPane text component supports different kinds of content via a
>   plug-in mechanism called an EditorKit. Because HTML is a
>   very popular format of content, some support is provided by default.
>   The default support is provided by this class, which supports HTML
>   version 3.2 (with some extensions), and is migrating toward version
>   4.0.

Notice the subtle suggestion at the bottom of the tutorial [Swing HTML Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html):

> If you are programming in JavaFX, see HTML Editor.

Also, they point out a bug:

> Note also that when a button is disabled, its HTML text unfortunately remains black,
>   instead of becoming gray. (Refer to bug #4783068 to see if this situation changes.)

Bottom line: HTML support is very basic and not very well implemented.

Answer (score 0):

A common java library for producing webpages is spring MVC.
The folowing page mentions support for the spring mvc's jsp tag libraries and html5.

http://www.thymeleaf.org/thvsjsp.html